# Pycharm installed but not opening

Tags: software-installation, python

I am running Ubuntu 14.04/GNOME 3.8.4 on 15 MBP Duel Boot. I am new to Linux and Python (Pycharm ide).

I have downloaded the Pycharm "files" from the software center but cannot run the program. The icon comes up in the side bar but when I click it nothing happens.

I have tried "./" and only the code appers in "gedit". Please help Oracle java is already installed

Comment: Have you tried running the `pycharm.sh` file?

Comment: I click it and the "gedit" text editor opens.

Comment: At first go the the directory where the `pycharm.sh` file is by `cd /path/to/file` and then run `bash pycharm.sh`

Comment: run "bash pycharm.sh" in the shell?

Comment: Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=350m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.   This is the error i received.

Comment: At first you need to fix the JVM error....check the parameter `MaxPermSize`

Comment: I typed this in and it said command could not be found

Comment: Thats not a command....your java is trying to run with teh parameter `MaxPermSize=350m` causing the failure to create JVM..how did you install java?

Comment: sudo apt-get install java

Comment: Whats the answer? It might help future readers..

Comment: I followed these instructions  http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-pycharm-3-4-on-ubuntu-14-04-linux-mint-17-pinguy-os-14-04-and-other-ubuntu-14-04-derivatives/

Comment: @PLC, if you could provide the steps you followed as an answer below and then accept it as correct it would be helpful to others, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps;

```
wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu trusty-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pycharm
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

1. Downloaded the `.tar` file from https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux
2. Extracted the tar file

   `sudo tar xzf pycharm-*.tar.gz -C /opt/`
3. Entered the extracted folder through my terminal

   `cd /opt/pycharm-community-2020.3.4/`
4. If you do ls, you'll see a "/bin" folder. I entered that folder

   `cd bin/`
5. There is a file named "pycharm.sh", I executed it

   `sh pycharm.sh`

The above steps are given in pycharm's official documentation at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installation-guide.html#standalone